# What is the canonical way to execute code directly from a QEMU device?

Tags: c, qemu, sparc

I'm modeling a particular evaluation board, which has a leon3 processor and several banks of MRAM mapped to specific addresses.  My goal is to start qemu-system-sparc using my bootloader ELF, and then jump to the base address of a MRAM bank to begin executing bare-metal programs therein.  To this end, I have been able to successfully run my bootloader and jump to the first instruction, but QEMU immediately stops and exits without reporting any error/trap.  I can also run the bare-metal programs in isolation by passing them in ELF format as a kernel to qemu-system-sparc.

**Short version: Is there a canonical way to set up a device such that code can be executed from it directly?  What steps do I need to take when compiling that code to allow it to execute correctly?**

I modeled the MRAM as a device with a MemoryRegion, along with the appropriate read and write operations to expose a heap-allocated array with my program.  In my board code (modified version of qemu/hw/sparc/leon3.c), writes to the MRAM address are mapped to the MemoryRegion of the device.  Using printfs, I am reporting reads and writes in the style of the unimplemented device (qemu/hw/misc/unimp.c), and I have verified that I am reading and writing to the device correctly.

Unfortunately, this did not work with respect to running the code on the device.  I can see the read immediately after the bootloader jumps to the base address of my device, but the instruction read doesn't actually do anything.  The bootloader uses a void function pointer, which is tied to the address of the MRAM device to induce a jump.

Another approach I tried is creating an alias to my device starting from address 0;  I thought perhaps that my binary has all its addresses set relative to zero, so by mapping writes from addresses [0, MRAM_SIZE) as an alias to my device base address, the code will end up reading the corresponding instructions in the device MemoryRegion.

This approach failed an assert in memory.c:

```
static void memory_region_add_subregion_common(MemoryRegion *mr,
                                               hwaddr offsset,
                                               MemoryRegion *subregion)
{
    assert(!subregion->container);
    subregion->container = mr;
    subregion->addr = offset;
    memory_region_update_container_subregions(subregion);
}
```

What do I need to do to coerce QEMU to execute the code in my MRAM device?  Do I need to produce a binary with absolute addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of QEMU were simply unable to handle execution from anything other than RAM or ROM, and attempting to do so would give a "qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM" error. QEMU 3.1 and later fixed this limitation, and now can execute code from anywhere -- though execution from a device will be much much slower than executing from RAM.

You mention that you "modeled the MRAM as a device with a MemoryRegion, along with the appropriate read and write operations to expose a heap-allocated array". This sounds like it is probably the wrong approach -- it will work but be very slow. If the MRAM appears to the guest as being like RAM, then model it as RAM (ie with a RAM MemoryRegion). If it's like RAM for reading but writes need to do something other than just-write-to-the-memory (or need to do that some of the time), then model it using a "romd" region, the same way the existing pflash devices do. Nonetheless, modelling it as a device with pure read and write functions should work, it'll just be horribly slow.

The assertion you've run into is the one that says "you can't put a memory region into two things at once" -- the 'subregion' you've passed in is already being used somewhere else, but you've tried to put it into a second container. If you have a MemoryRegion that you need to have appear in two places in the physical memory map, then you need to: create the MemoryRegion; create an alias MemoryRegion that aliases the real one; map the actual MemoryRegion into one place; map the alias into the other. There are plenty of examples of this in existing board models in QEMU.

More generally, you need to figure out what the evaluation board hardware actually is, and then model that. If the eval board has the MRAM visible at multiple physical addresses, then yes, use an alias MR. If it doesn't, then the problem is somewhere else and you need to figure out what's actually happening, not try to bodge around it with aliases that don't exist on the real hardware. QEMU's debug logging (various -d suboptions, plus -D file to log to a file) can be useful for checking what the emulated CPU is really doing in this early bootup phase -- but watch out as the logs can be quite large and they are sometimes tricky to interpret unless you know a little about QEMU internals.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  At the moment performance is not as important as proof of concept, but I will adapt these to use romd MemoryRegions in the future.  The evaluation board has its MRAM banks off-chip, and they are accessed directly by the bootloader code.  That said, assuming I get the addressing correct, will I be able to simply jump into that code by setting the pc, npc?

Comment: Yes, the guest code should be able to just jump into the MRAM the same as it would any other area of memory.